# Dartlang wait more than one future

Tags: dart, future

I want to do something after a lot of future functions are done, but I do not know how to write the code in dart?
the code is like this:

```
for (var d in data) {
  d.loadData().then()
}
// when all loaded
// do something here
```

but I don't want to wait for them one by one:

```
for (var d in data) {
  await d.loadData(); // NOT NEED THIS
}
```

how to write those code in dart?

Answer (score 221):

You can use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to wait for a list of futures:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future main() async {
  var data = [];
  var futures = <Future>[];
  for (var d in data) {
    futures.add(d.loadData());
  }
  await Future.wait(futures);
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a0d8b035b1eb6f864a3d309817fb1ca2)

Comment: You can use `map` as well: `await Future.wait(data.map((d)=>d.loadData()))`.

Comment: Would like to point out that to fix the above code, do the following:
```List<Future> futures = [];```
instead of `var`

Comment: Since it is not 100% clear from the question or answer or docs: the processes all start at the same time and run in parallel see [dartpad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/20ae2ced5f4d5dfc760339b4de6584f5)

Comment: That's not entirely true. They are started one after the other, because in Dart within one isolate only a single code execution can run, but when one of the running yields, because it waits for some async call to complete, then the next is started (or continued) before the previous completes. So they run concurrently (not parallel) according to Darts event-queue driven method.

Comment: @JannieTheunissen I'd like to appreciate the clarity in your example. Years ago when I was wrestling with this in JS.. I learnt it this very same way. Thanks & great work!!!

Comment: This doesn't work with FutureOr though

Answer (score 23):

Existing answer gives enough information, but I want to add a note/warning.
As stated in the docs:

> The value of the returned future will be a list of all the values that were produced ***in the order*** that the futures are provided by iterating futures.

So, that means that the example below will return `4` as the first element (index 0), and `2` as the second element (index 1).

```
import 'dart:async';

Future main() async {
  print('start');

  List<int> li = await Future.wait<int>([
    fetchLong(),  // longer (which gives 4) is first
    fetchShort(), // shorter (which gives 2) is second
  ]);

  print('results: ${li[0]} ${li[1]}'); // results: 4 2
}

Future<int> fetchShort() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    print('Short!');
    return 2;
  });
}

Future<int> fetchLong() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    print('Long!');
    return 4;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to wait for multiple futures of different types and also support null-safety then you can add a helper function similar to the following when using **Dart >= 3.0**:

```
Future<(T1, T2)> waitConcurrently<T1, T2>(
  Future<T1> future1,
  Future<T2> future2,
) async {
  late T1 result1;
  late T2 result2;

  await Future.wait([
    future1.then((value) => result1 = value),
    future2.then((value) => result2 = value)
  ]);

  return (result1, result2);
}
```

**Dart < 3.0** does not support tuples natively, but there is a package from Google which does: https://pub.dev/packages/tuple

```
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';

Future<Tuple2<T1, T2>> waitConcurrently<T1, T2>(
    Future<T1> future1, Future<T2> future2) async {
  late T1 result1;
  late T2 result2;

  await Future.wait([
    future1.then((value) => result1 = value),
    future2.then((value) => result2 = value)
  ]);

  return Tuple2(result1, result2);
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you @tobias-marschall... Here's my example using your helper method!!! https://gist.github.com/marcellodesales/39857e464b38167f0631150ee6238943

Comment: What is the purpose of returning `Future.value` of the result tuple? Is it not redundant given that the result of an async function is already a Future?

Comment: @Aaron there is no reason other than that it was a mistake. I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I'd like to supplement Günter Zöchbauer's answer with `FutureOr` variant. You'll need to convert your `FutureOr<T>` variable to `Future<T>` first and then call `wait`:

```
Future.wait(list.map((x) async => x))
```