# Analog of Promise.all in Dart?

Tags: dart, future

Is there an existing API to group a list of `Future` object into one so that I can wait for all to complete? Like in javascript's `Promise.all`.

Comment: Something like Future.wait? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Comment: definitely something like this, please fire an answer

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176092/9157799

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `Future.wait` method documented here:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Future.wait`

**Example**

```
var futures = await Future.wait([     
      getAddress(),      
      getTeam(),    
      getEvents(),
    ]);
```