# How to filter and display max values of each collection with flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I search a solution to extract all max value from all collections

I have a firestore structure like this

```
Collection      document          data


2020-08-01      user1       votes:1, data_user1
                user4       votes:4, data_user4     // =>win
                user8       votes:2, data_user8

2020-08-02      user11      votes:3, data_user11    // =>win
                user12      votes:2, data_user12
                user17      votes:1, data_user17

2020-08-03      user21      votes:3, data_user21    // =>win
                user23      votes:2, data_user23
```

So I try to filter and get in a list all wins data users

```
My_win_list:[
user4   :   data_user4
user11  :   data_user11
user21  :   data_user21
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ordering](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#ordering):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('2020-08-01')
  .orderBy('votes', descending: true)
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

You can easily loops through the required collections as they seem to be dates. You can use [Future.wait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692367/13130697) to run all promises simultaneously.