# Flutter Parallel Network call

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

I am new in flutter. I need to call 5 API network calls in a single screen. It is taking very long time while i am using Async/await. How can we execute it on separate threads parallelly using isolate or anything else like it?

Comment: You can use .then instead of await so and get value to replace what you need when it’s done without blocking each api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use isolate for this purpose isolate is a sort of  multi threading in dart. Isolate creates a new thread and execute operation on the new thread so that the load will be distributed. You cannot send variables as a data back and forth but use port to send messages.

Here is a  simple example of isolate with an API call and sending data back to the main thread using port.

First lets create a function which will be the entrypoint of isolate:

```
static entryPoint(SendPort sendPort)async{
    var response = await http.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita');
    sendPort.send(response.body); //sending data back to main thread's function
}
```

Now lets create isolate:

```
static void callApi()async{
    var recievePort = new ReceivePort(); //creating new port to listen data
    await Isolate.spawn(entryPoint, recievePort.sendPort);//spawing/creating new thread as isolates.
    recievePort.listen((message) {  //listening data from isolate
      print(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I return the result to main isolate?? any code example please.

Comment: You cant return or share the data. one thing you can do is  that send message using the send port and receive the message the message in the port as i have done in the answer. If you want to know further open a new question and provide the link here.

Comment: @AbhayKumar hi, nice explaination and an example, Can i add Isolate inside Future.wait?
For example, I have 300 ids, and I try to implemenet like this
Future.wait(ids.map((id) => Isolate.spawn(reqData, id));
and the process is not running, did it right to implement Isolate that way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dio` package and call multiple concurrent API requests, do check the documentation:

```
Package: https://pub.dev/packages/dio
```

Comment: I tried Dio package , but it seems it is working as normal http package. can you help with some sample code for concurrent API request

Answer (score 0):

You can use Future.wait()

[Here is the answer with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176121)

Comment: I tried Future.wait(). but it seems it execute all the calls on the same thread. so it also taking long time, although it is executing parallelly.

Comment: I thought the issue was the time it takes to receive a response from each call. If you have cpu bound computations to perform after receiving a response then isolates are the way to go.