# Flutter Firestore - How to get data from a Document Reference in a Document Field?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a Self-learning app with differente questions types. Right now, one of the questions have a field containing a list of DocumentReferences:

[image]

In Flutter, I have the following code:

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> questionsRef = firestore
.collection('questions')
.where('lesson_id', isEqualTo: lessonId);

await questionsRef.get().then((snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    var questionTemp;
    switch (document.data()['question_type']) {


      ....



      case 'cards':
        questionTemp = CardsQuestionModel.fromJson(document.data());
        break;


      ....


    }
    questionTemp.id = document.id;
    questions.add(questionTemp);
  });
});
```

Now, with "questionTemp" I can access all the fields (lesson_id,options,question_type, etc..), but when it comes to the "cards" field, how Can I access the data from that document reference?

Is there a way to tell firestore.instance to get the data from those references automatically? Or do I need to make a new call for each one? and, if so, how can I do that?

Thank you for your support in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell firestore.instance to get the data from those
> references automatically? Or do I need to make a new call for each
> one?

No there isn't any way to get these documents automatically. You need to build, **for each array element**, the corresponding [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) and fetch the document.

To build the reference, use the [`doc()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/doc.html) method

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("cards/WzU...");
```

and then use the [`get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) method on this `DocumentReference`.

```
docRef
.get()
.then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    print('Document exists on the database');
  }
});
```

---

Concretely, you can loop over the `cards` Array and pass all the Futures returned by the `get()` method to the [`wait()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html) method which "waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results". See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176092/dartlang-wait-more-than-one-future) for more details and also note that "the value of the returned future will be a list of all the values that were produced **in the order that the futures are provided** by iterating futures."

Comment: Thank you very much! I handled the problem with this recommendation using the Future.wait().